# OSX, iOS WebView: how to perform client identity authentication like safari

Tags: objective-c, macos, wkwebview

How to perform authentication with a server which demands client identity certificate from OSX keychain. I see safari displaying a dialog [immage below] with a list of certificates that user can select. How can this be achieved inside an OSX app? WKNavigationDelegate does provide callback `- (void)webView:(WKWebView * nonnull)webView didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *nonnull)challenge completionHandler:(void (^ nonnull)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition,NSURLCredential * nullable credential))completionHandler` but it doesn't get invoked.Is there any special handling required?

Any help would be appreciable.

[image]